# Vuetify/Lib Polyfilling for IE11 isn't working - SCRIPT1002: Syntax Error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, vuetify.js, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, babel-polyfill

I'm trying to reference `vuetify/lib` with the usual `import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib"`, but when I do, the application chokes in IE11 with `SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'`.

If I change the reference to `import Vuetify from "vuetify"` - without the `/lib` portion - it doesn't throw the error.

Note that I'm not actually *using* vuetify anywhere yet.  I don't have a single Vuetify component or call; I'm just adding the library.

Now that I've ostensibly got vuetify included and parsed happily by IE11, I'd like to use some of the components.  If I put *any* vuetify components in my template, IE11 throws a `Script1002: Syntax Error` message.

Anyone have a suggestion to make this actually work?

**Index.cshtml**

```html
<v-app>
  <div id="reportApp"></div>
</v-app>
```

**Entry Point**

```js
// polyfills
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";

import Vue from "vue"
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css"
import reportFilter from "./reportFilter.vue"

const options = {
    el: "#reportApp",
    render: h => h(reportFilter)
};

export default new Vue(options);
```

**reportFilter.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div>
      <!-- this will throw a syntax error -->
      <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="primary"
      ></v-progress-circular>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        name: 'report-filter',
        data: function(){
            return {
                dataTypeList: [
                    { value: "1", text: "one" },
                    { value: "2", text: "two" },
                    { value: "3", text: "three" }
                ]
            }
        },
    }

</script>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require("vuetify-loader/lib/plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: jsEntries,  // setting jsEntries removed for clarity
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
            // other rules for css/sass/etc removed for clarity
            /*javascript*/{
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: [
                    /node_modules/,
                    /bower_components/
                ],
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            [
                                "@babel/preset-env",
                                {
                                    "targets": {
                                        "browsers": [
                                            "last 2 versions",
                                            "ie >= 11"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "corejs": "3",
                                    "useBuiltIns": "entry"
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            /*vue*/{
                test: /\.vue$/i,
                use: "vue-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./wwwroot/dist/js/"),
        publicPath: "/wwwroot/dist/js/"
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: "vue/dist/vue.js"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you digested the docs https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#ie-11-safari-9-support ? I do not use Vuetify - so I this is just a link...

Comment: @madflow yeah I've done my best, but I don't see a solution in there.

Comment: The same problem occurs on me, I googled every corner to look for the answer. I tried my best too, nothing works. So, if you find the solution someday, please come back here to paste the answer, thank you.

Comment: Does this error occur during your development AND production? what if you try to build and then run it.

Comment: could you share your package.json

Comment: plz look at my done before. it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users in the Vuejs forums having a similar issue reported success in using babel to polyfill for this specific issue.

My suggestion is to install the babel polyfill, import it in your app.js and configure the babel.config.js as illustrated [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuejs-not-working-in-ie11-script1002-syntax-error/48195)

If you are going to be actively using Vuetify you should also have Vue.use(Vuetify) prior to the declaration of your options app otherwise Vue will not know that it needs to be using that package.

Answer (score 1):

On my side `SCRIPT1002: Syntax Error` was resolved by updating `webpack-dev-server`.

Try to change `webpack-dev-server` version to `3.8.2` and remove `node_modules` and `npm install` again.

One more.

// .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

// babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
}
```

> You can install vuetify in three ways:
>
> **default installation**
>
> The first (and
>   recommended) way is to utilize the vuetify-loader or what we call
>   automatic A-la-carte. This will ensure that your application only uses
>   the features and styles from Vuetify that are needed, significantly
>   reducing your application's compiled size and is setup you will see in
>   a new vue-cli-3 project. Keep in mind, when importing from
>   **vuetify/lib**, the necessary styles are automatically imported for you.
>
> **vue-cli a-la-carte installation**
>
> You can also manually import individual components without the need
>   for the vuetify-loader. This is considered manual A-la-carte.
>
> (And about your done: `import Vuetify from 'vuetify'`)
>
> **vue-cli full installation**
>
> The last method will import and setup all of Vuetify's features and
>   styles. As stated above, it is still **recommended** that you utilize the
>   **vuetify-loader** if at all possible. For this install, you will need to
>   manually import the Vuetify styles. This is also the process used when
>   bootstrapping Vuetify through a browser as opposed to compiling.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are using Vue CLI.
That type of issue with polyfill in IE 11 can be resolved by adding npm package name (package causing syntax error) to transpileDependencies section in vue.config.js like is descripted at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#browserslist

In my case it was 3 packages, and now my config looks like:

```
    transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify',
    'query-string',
    'strict-uri-encode',
    'split-on-first'
  ],
```

Package name causing the error you will find in browser console. Go to error details, you should find package name somewhere near code line causing the error.